# For loop iterator 'leaking' into pipe write call to child process

Tags: c++, pipe, fork

In this program I make a pipe, then a fork. The parent fork calculates stuff in a for loop and writes it to a file. The child fork uses popen to run gnuplot and create a plot that updates in 'real time'. To time these replotting I use the pipe and write from the parent to the child a single char.

The problem is that the for loop 'i' seems to get sent in the write call. I noticed this because the child process kept ending early, always when i == 88, which is ascii 'X', which is the exit condition in the child process. I'm not the most familiar with forks and pipes and so I'm not sure how this is happening.

Here is the for loop where I believe the problem is. I added the if else statement here to change 'i' so it isn't 88 when write() is called and it allowed the program to run all the way through.

I'll include the full code underneath that. Thank you for any help.

```
 msg = 'E';    
       for (int i = 0; i < details.nt-1; i++){    
            Vupdate(V, I, details, coeff);    
            VsUpdate(V, I, i, details, coeff);    
            Vlupdate(V, I, details, coeff);    
            iupdate(I, V, details, coeff);    
            std::cout << "At i = " << i << std::endl;    
        // file creation for V and I here    
            CreateFile(V, I, details);    
            //msg = 'E';    
            if(i != 88){    
            write(pipefd[1], &msg, strlen(&msg));
            }else{    
                i = 89;    
                write(pipefd[1], &msg, strlen(&msg)); 
                i = 88;    
            }    
                   
            system("sleep 0.01");    
        }
```

Full Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <unistd.h>
//#include <signal.h>

// for exec() and NewPID()
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string.h>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

//for new replot method
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

/*
 * Try using refresh and replot  and volatile instead of reread.
 */


typedef struct{ 
    double C;
    double L;
    double d;
    double ncells;
    double cfln;
    double simtime;
    int Rs;
    int RL;
    int load_case;
    double CL;
    double G;
    double R;
    double LL;
    double Zo;
    double vo;
    double dx;
    double dt;
    int nx;
    int nt;
    double Vs;
}details_t;

typedef struct{
    double cv;
    double ci;
    double c1;
    double c2;
}coeff_t;

void Vupdate(double V[], double I[], details_t& details, coeff_t& coeff);
void VsUpdate(double V[], double I[], int n, details_t& details, coeff_t& coeff);
double Vgourd(int n, double dt);
void Vlupdate(double V[], double I[], details_t& details, coeff_t& coeff);
void init_parameters(details_t& details);
void init_coeff(coeff_t& coeff, details_t& details);
void iupdate(double I[], double V[], details_t& details, coeff_t& coeff);
void CreateFile(double V[], double I[], details_t& details);
void plot(double P[]);
std::string exec(const char* cmd);
int NewPID();
void plot2(double P[]);
void replot(double P[]);


int main(){
    details_t details;
    coeff_t coeff;
    
    init_parameters(details);
    init_coeff(coeff, details);

    double V[details.nx] = {0};
    double I[details.nx-1] = {0};
    CreateFile(V, I, details);
    // additions
    int pipefd[2];
    pid_t pid;
    char buf;
    char msg = 'O';
    pipe(pipefd);
    pid = fork();
    

    if(pid == 0){ 
        close(pipefd[1]);
        FILE* gnuPipe = popen("gnuplot -persist", "w");
        fflush(gnuPipe);
        fprintf(gnuPipe, "plot 'V.txt'\n");
        fflush(gnuPipe);
        while (read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1) > 0){
               if(buf == 'G'){break;}
        }
        while (read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1) > 0) // read while EOF
        {     
           if(buf == 'D'){
               std::cout << "Got D" << std::endl;
           }else if(buf == 'E'){
               std::cout << "Got E" << std::endl;
               fprintf(gnuPipe, "set yrange [-2:2]\n");
               fprintf(gnuPipe, "set title \"Cave of Wonder\"\n");
               fprintf(gnuPipe, "replot\n");
               fflush(gnuPipe);
           }else if(buf == 'X'){
               std::cout << "Got X" << std::endl;
               break;
           }
           
        }
           
       std::cout << "Closing cuz X" << std::endl; 
           //write(1, "\n", 1);
           close(pipefd[0]); // close the read-end of the pipe
           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "parent id: " << pid << std::endl;
        std::cout << "parent get: " << getpid() << std::endl; 
        close(pipefd[0]); // close the read-end of the pipe, I'm not going to use it
       std::cout << "enter G:"; std::cin >> msg;
       write(pipefd[1], &msg, strlen(&msg)); // send the content of argv[1] to the reader
       char INPUT[] = "DE";
       msg = 'E';
       for (int i = 0; i < details.nt-1; i++){
            Vupdate(V, I, details, coeff);
            VsUpdate(V, I, i, details, coeff);
            Vlupdate(V, I, details, coeff);
            iupdate(I, V, details, coeff);
            std::cout << "At i = " << i << std::endl;
        // file creation for V and I here
            CreateFile(V, I, details);
            //msg = 'E';
            if(i != 88){
            write(pipefd[1], &msg, strlen(&msg)); // send the content of argv[1] to the reader
            }else{
                i = 89;
                write(pipefd[1], &msg, strlen(&msg)); // send the content of argv[1] to the reader
                i = 88;
            }

            system("sleep 0.01");
        } 

       std::cout << "enter to end:"; std::cin >> msg;
       std::cout << "clsing pipefd[1] now" << std::endl;
       close(pipefd[1]); // close the write-end of the pipe, thus sending EOF to the reader
           wait(NULL); // wait for the child process to exit before I do the same
           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
       }
    return 0;
}
/*
// old
    
        for (int i = 0; i < details.nx; i++){
           // std::cout << "V[" << i << "] = " << V[i] << std::endl;
        }
    } // pid > 0 end case
    
    if(pid > 0) {
        std::cout << pid << std::endl;
        
        int K = NewPID();
        if(K > 0){
            std::cout << "killerPID is: " << K << std::endl;
            std::string cmd = "kill " + std::to_string(K);
            system(cmd.c_str());
        }
    }
    if(pid == 0){
        std::cout << "child process x: " << getpid() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "who done it: " << getpid() << std::endl;
    return 0; 
}*/

void Vupdate(double V[], double I[], details_t& details, coeff_t& coeff){
    for(int k = 1; k < details.nx-1; k++){
    V[k] = V[k] - coeff.cv * (I[k] - I[k-1]);
    }
}

void VsUpdate(double V[], double I[], int n, details_t& details, coeff_t& coeff){
    double Vs = Vgourd(n, details.dt);
    if(details.Rs > 0){
        V[0] = coeff.c1 * (coeff.c2 * V[0] - I[0] + Vs / details.Rs);
    }else{
        V[0] = Vs; // if Rs = 0, then V[0] = Vs
    }
}

double Vgourd(int n, double dt){
    double t_rise = 200*pow(10,-12);
    double t_fall = t_rise;
    double t_peak = 500*pow(10,-12);

    double t = (n-0.5)*dt;
    double Vsauce;
    if(t < 0)
        { Vsauce = 0;}
    else if(t >= 0 && t <= t_rise)
        { Vsauce = 2*(t / t_rise);}
    else if(t >= t_rise && t <= t_rise + t_peak)
        { Vsauce = 2;}
    else if(t >= t_rise + t_peak && t <= t_rise + t_peak + t_fall)
        { Vsauce = 2*(t_rise + t_peak + t_fall - t) / t_fall;}
    else {Vsauce = 0;}
    //std::cout << "Vsauce at n:" << n << " = " << Vsauce << std::endl;
    return Vsauce;
}


void Vlupdate(double V[],double I[], details_t& details, coeff_t& coeff){
    // voltage at load node
    V[details.nx] = coeff.c1 * (coeff.c2 * V[details.nx] + I[details.nx-1]);

}


void iupdate(double I[], double V[], details_t& details, coeff_t& coeff){
    for(int k = 0; k < details.nx - 1; k++){
    I[k] = I[k] - coeff.ci * (V[k+1] - V[k]);
    }
}


void init_parameters(details_t& details){
// Initialize variable
    details.C = 100*pow(10,-12); // F/m
    details.L = 250*pow(10,-9); // H/m
    details.d = 0.5; // m
    details.ncells = 100;
    details.cfln = 1;
    details.simtime = 5*pow(10,-9);
    details.Rs = 50;  // Source Resistance
    details.RL = 50;  // Load Resistance
    details.load_case = 1;
    
    details.CL = 0;
    details.G = 0;
    details.R = 0;
    details.LL = 0;

    details.Zo = pow((details.L/details.C),0.5);
    details.vo = 1.0/sqrt(details.L*details.C);

    details.dx = details.d / details.ncells;
    details.dt = details.cfln * details.dx / details.vo; 
    details.nx = details.ncells + 1;
    details.nt =(int)(details.simtime / details.dt);
    
}


void init_coeff(coeff_t& coeff, details_t& details){
    // if load_case = 1
    coeff.cv = details.dt/(details.C*details.dx);
    coeff.ci = details.dt/(details.L*details.dx); // iupdate
    double b1 = details.C * details.dx * 0.5 / details.dt;
    double b2 = 0.5 / details.RL;
    coeff.c1 = 1.0 / (b1 + b2);
    coeff.c2 = b1 - b2;
}


void CreateFile(double V[], double I[], details_t& details){
    std::ofstream out1, out2;
    out1.open("V.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
    out2.open("I.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);


    for(int k = 0; k < details.nx; k++){
    out1 << k+1 << "\t" << V[k] << "\n";
    }

    for(int k = 0; k < details.nx-1; k++){
    out2 << k << "\t" << I[k] << "\n";
    }

    out1.close();
    out2.close();

}


void plot(double P[]){
    std::ifstream f;
    f.open("file");
    std::string cmd;
    std::getline(f, cmd);
    std::cout << "in my file: " << cmd << std::endl; 
    system(cmd.c_str());
}


std::string exec(const char* cmd){
    std::array<char, 128> buffer;
    std::string result;
    std::shared_ptr<FILE> pipe(popen(cmd, "r"), pclose);
    while(!feof(pipe.get())){
        if(fgets(buffer.data(), 128, pipe.get()) != nullptr)
            result += buffer.data();
    }
    return result;
}


int NewPID(){
    std::string read = exec("ps aux");
//  std::cout << read << std::endl;

    std::stringstream check1(read);
    std::string tmp;
    std::vector <std::string> tokens;
    
    while(getline(check1,tmp, '\n'))
    {
        std::stringstream check2(tmp);
        std::string tmp2;
        copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(check2),
             std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
             std::back_inserter(tokens));
        
        for(int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++){
//          std::cout << i << tokens[i] << std::endl;
            if(tokens[i] == "gnuplot"){
//              std::cout << "Winner: " << tokens[1] << std::endl;
                int T = std::stoi(tokens[1]);
                std::cout << "Token 1 as int is: " << T << std::endl;
                return T;
            }
        }
        tokens.clear();
    }
    return 0;
}

void plot2(double P[]){
    std::ifstream f;
    f.open("load.file");
    std::string cmd;
    std::getline(f, cmd);
    std::cout << "in my file: " << cmd << std::endl; 
    system(cmd.c_str());
}

void replot(double P[]){
    std::ifstream f;
    f.open("load2.file");
    std::string cmd;
    std::getline(f, cmd);
    std::cout << "in my file: " << cmd << std::endl; 
    system(cmd.c_str());
}
```

Comment: Hint: What does strlen do?

Comment: Oh yea I think I see how that could be the issue. strlen(x) returns the size of x. A char is 1 byte, but what is the size of an address. I'll try it out. Thanks.

Comment: That is wrong - strlen(x) does not return the size of x.

Comment: If the child process could not read "G", the first "while" continues. Is it expected

Comment: @nhatnq Yea that is just there to let me halt the program. I don't really expect reading G to fail but I wansn't going to keep this while loop after I got the rest of the stuff working. You have to type G into the terminal, it's surronded but sometimes by stuff  like 'can't fine yrange...'

Comment: the second "while" of the child process exited once the pipe is closed by the parent process `close(pipefd[1]);`. Eventually the child process is terminated

Comment: @user253751 Well it returns size_t, unsigned int identifying the number of chars in a char array, not including the null terminator. Does a single char get a null terminator in runtime? Anyways I see that just using 1 in place of strlen(&msg) fixes the issue I was having. But strlen()'s behaviour still confuses me. I wrote an isolated case comparing intializing with "char msg" and "char msg[]" and only found wierd behaviour with the first case. Just adding variables changed output of strlen(). I'm guessing "char msg" doens't get a null terminator and using strnlen(&msg,1) masked extra reads.

Comment: @Hackem2bits Not even that! It does not return the number of chars in a char array. And you don't get a null terminator unless you ask for one. (Most people don't realize this, because writing a string with `""` asks for one)

Comment: @user253751 strlen returns the number of bytes or characters in a string, which is null terminated. In my code, I'm sending it a char pointer which doesn't the the null terminator strlen() expects and so strlen() has undefined behaviour. Still from what I see it is return the value 2, which just happens to read in the value of i, and since the read() call only reads 1 byte at a time I still get my E msg sent but also now the ascii equivalent of 0 and 1 and 2 and so on until it gets to 88. I'm still confused as to why it strlen() stopped at 2, was it just chance that memory had a null character

Comment: @Hackem2bits Yes! Good thinking! That is why this doesn't work properly. You get a cookie. Yes, it's probably coincidence that the compiler decided to store i right after msg. Since almost all CPUs these days are little-endian, the number 1 is stored as the bytes 1 then 0 then 0 then 0 and the first 0 byte is seen as a null terminator

Comment: @nhatnq I haven't seen this behavior. Unless you mean that 'X' is sent from the parent to the child and then the child closed its end of the pipe. I got the code to run corretly now. The problem stemmed from the write() call in the parent process. There, strlen(&msg) return a number larger than 1 which meant I was sending data starting from the address of msg and beyond it, which happened to be the variable "i" (for me at least, I don't know if it would be different for someone else's memory allocations.

Comment: @user253751 Wow what a trip. Thanks alot for the help. Much appreciated

Comment: do you still need to know how to fix it?

Comment: @user253751 I was go excited to find out what the issue was I forgot about solving it. I did get it to work by just writing a 1 in the place of strlen(). But to still pass text I'm going to look into it.

Comment: writing 1 is correct in this case. You can also write sizeof(char) or sizeof(msg) (both of them are always 1 so writing 1 is perfectly fine)

Comment: @user253751 So I rewrote the initialization of msg from "char msg = 'O' " to "char msg[]{"O"}. The idea being that larger text msg can be sent if needed, though they won't for this case since it's just an enable and exit signal. Thanks you very much for all your time.